# How can I link sockets to PIDs in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I've developed a utility to monitor the network usage (for TCP/UDP/IP) [nettop](http://nettop.youlink.org/), and in order to link packets captured with libpcap to their respective processes, I basically scan the virtual filesystem *`/proc/net/(tcp|udp)(6)`* and *`/proc/<pid>/fd`*.

Is there a better more efficient way to do so?

Cheers,
Ema

Comment: I think there isn't a better nor more efficient way.

Comment: Are you sure you want to map sockets? I wonder as I do not see how libpcap would return you sockets (aka socket descriptors aka a process' file descriptors) . Do you probably mean "ports"?

Comment: @alk you end up mapping _socket:[....]_ file descriptor, so you map ports also with libpcap, but then to bind to process, you need to map port to socket and socket to pid. So there's two levels of indirection I believe and socket mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so - it's how the `fuser(1)` command does it.  The source for `fuser` might give some insights about additional things you may want to consider, though (esp. with IPv4 vs. IPv6).